# Changing category url key is not updating URL Rewrites

Tags: magento2.3, url-rewrite

I have a category called "Sport Shoes" in magento. The category has lots of subcategories and products on it. It's url key is "sport-shoes".

After changing category url key to "shoes-for-sports", no magento URL Rewrite is updated. All redirects are the same and no category or product url containg "shoes-for-sports" is working.

I have tried re-indexing products but that didn't solve the issue. I do not dare to use some kind of url regenerate extension, cause my website contains 150k+ products. It would take days to complete such a proccess.

But this is feature that should work ok in magento by default.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It was not there in 2.3 when I needed it.  I think they have now removed the config to not regenerate  on save... as this was recommended never to be off.  I had speed issues with my script to fix and with some modules I tried.

[elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) is the module to use being fast, flexible and reliable.  From the readme...

> This extension adds console commands to be able to regenerate; a product rewrite URL based on its url path; a category rewrite URL based on its url path; a category URL path based on its URL key and its parent categories.

Answer (score 0):

Add category URL rewrite manually. 
Follow these steps

```
Marketing > URL Rewrites > Add New URL Rewtie > [ Choose 'For Category' ] > Save
```

This will fix your issue. Don't need to add 150k+ products again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Don't tell me that there is no way to regenerate URL rewrites without an extension?
My URL gots rewritten. I guess when you save the product it does.
It was not allowing me to create a product the urls were the default for categories.
That is the sample data. mens and womans.
I wanted it to be laptops and desktops.
Even though URL key was changed to the above.
Now I just created new categories. I had problems creating them with the same name. It kept saying there are redirects of the same name.
Then I just renamed the old categories and unchecked create permanent redirect.
Reindexed it and everything was working like a charm.
I guess you have to find some way to save the categories and products then it does created a redirect.
I don't know if that would work for imported products.